# Shelve local changes and get latest with git cmd

Tags: git

New to git

I was making rather large changes in the main branch of our project which are still local to my machine. My friend just committed some large changes to our project in the main branch.

How do I set aside my local changes and pull his stuff so that I can test it and perhaps commit changes from that pull?

I'm using git bash on windows.

Comment: By the way, do you know about the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)? It's free, and I learned almost everything I know about Git from it. I recommend chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5.

Comment: @Cupcake, thanks I'll take a look. I follow the tutorial on the official git website, but I was in the middle of a project so I wasn't able to try all of the features, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, stash your working copy changes (or make a temporary branch for them, but we'll go with stash for now):

```
$ git stash save "Stash message"
```

Then fetch your buddy's changes:

```
$ git fetch <remote> <branch>
```

If you like your buddy's changes, merge them into your local branch:

```
$ git merge <remote>/<branch>
```

Then if you want to restore your previous working copy, simply pop it:

```
$ git stash pop
```

Comment: And then *stop with the multiple people making changes on the main branch thing*. Use feature branches and proper merges. It's the git-way.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that branches are the way to go, we just wanted to take git for a spin, we normally use subversion.